# DefaultTableModel is empty even tho data is queried

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, resultset, defaulttablemodel

I try to put my ResultSet data into a JTable with help of DefaultTableModel class. As a solution I found a solution on Stackoverflow but modified it a bit (not really relevant here):

```
    public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount;++column) {
            columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
        }
        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount;++columnIndex) {
                vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
            }
            data.add(vector);
        }
        return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new DefaultTableModel(new Vector<>(), new Vector<>());
    }
}
```

While I debugged this code I was able to see that:

- ResultSet `rs` has data,
- `ColumnNames` is populated,
- RowCount is zero
- and I think the issue is this line `vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));`
  It looks like my vector becomes empty because `getObject()` returns already no data.

Can someone help me with this or explains where the issue is? When I bind my generated DefaultTableModel to my JTable it is empty (no data is shown).

Comment: Does `DefaultTableModel` have no rows upon existing the method ?

Comment: Yes the row count is zero @dev-null.

Comment: Code looks reasonable. You need to add debug code to verify that your loop execute as expected. If the row count is zero this tells me the ResultSet is empty.

Comment: The ResultSet is not empty and row count neither. Just the .add() is causing an empty data set ... why!?

Comment: What row count? Do you display the value of each Object as you add it to the Vector? This will confirm the Vector is created. The `add()` method is not the problem. We can't help you. You need to debug the code yourself. Add System.out statements inside every loop and every if statement to see exactly what code is being executed. One thing I just noticed. Why are you use `++columnIndex` the code is usually `columnIndex++`.

Comment: You can check out the `Table From Database Example` code found in [Table From Database](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/). It is complete working code. You just need to change the connections to the database and your select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the issue short time ago: the problem was the fact that the cursor was set to last row because other methods iterated over the same ResultSet already and thus the cursor had to be set to first row again with first-method of ResultSet class.

Comment: For anyone else reading this, this is why you copy a ResultSet into a List right away.  Passing a ResultSet around is dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for your hint @GilbertLeBlanc! I do that rarely but didn't know it is the usual way to go. Now I'm wiser ;).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the AbstractTableModel as a base. Some years ago, I found within the examples from Sun a class called JDBCAdapter.java. This class does, what you want. Search the web for this class and you will have something, that fulfills probably most of your needs.  It might be a challenge, if your application should be able to write changes back to the DB, but just for displaying the table its fine.